# digitalPin giving lower voltage than Vcc

Tags: voltage-level, attiny, resistor

I am using an ATTINY88 for a project that requires to turn on an LED. Right now I am using pin PA1(ADC7/PCINT25). I noted, however, that when the pin is ON, I get about half the voltage that is connected to Vcc. I checked the voltage in other pins and they are close to Vcc. Will anyone know, what could be the reason for this?

I figure this pin has an internal resistor enable, but I am not certain.

Comment: Do you have a resistor in series with the LED?

Comment: I disconnected everything from the pin and I still get half the Voltage in Vcc when that pin is HIGH. In fact, all the pins on that side of the chip give half the voltage when they are on, while other pins give voltage near Vcc. I think those pins on that side of the chip have a resistor enable???

Comment: this behaviour might happen if you have PA1 set as input and pull up resistor enabled. Check the datasheet for Port A sub-section. It defines that it will source current when enabled.

Comment: is there a way to disable such resistor? I have that pin set as OUTPUT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should connect the AVCC pin to VCC. From the datasheet (emphasis
mine):

> AV<sub>CC</sub> is the supply voltage pin for the A/D converter **and
>   a selection of I/O pins**. This pin should be externally connected to
>   V<sub>CC</sub> **even if the ADC is not used**. [...]
>
> The following pins receive their supply voltage from AV<sub>CC</sub>:
>   PC7, PC[5:0] and (in 32-lead pack- ages) **PA[1:0]**. All other I/O
>   pins take their supply voltage from V<sub>CC</sub>.

Comment: That sounds like a really bizarre design choice to me... reminds me why I use PIC and not Atmel chips ;)

Comment: @Majenko It is little bit bizare, but connecting AVcc to Vcc is stated in every datasheet for every AVR with AVcc pin. And yet it's common rookie mistake.

Comment: It probably makes internal wiring in the chip simpler, and possibly reduces noise.

Comment: do you know why is this needed (connecting AVcc to Vcc)?. My circuit works just fine without that connection and it includes several AnalogReads....also, I wonder if it will increase battery consumption? I will test this.

Comment: @Camilo: Why it is needed? The excerpt of the datasheet I quoted is, I think, quite explicit. Your circuit may work without that because 1) the internal logic is powered through VCC, 2) the AVCC node is getting some parasitic power through some I/O pins or some internal gates.

Comment: @NickGammon I would have thought it would have *increased* noise. Digital switching noise from the pins used for digital purposes imposed on the analog circuitry.

Comment: Yes, but those are the analog (ADC) pins anyway (of course you can use them for digital if you want). Having the ADC pins have *two* power sources could be complex (one for digital work, one for analog work). So if you stick to using the "digital-only" side for digital switching and the analog-side for analog reading, the two power supplies now keep them separate, rather than running an internal wire, with its digital noise from digital switching, from one side of the chip to the other. So I wouldn't call it bizarre. It sounds quite sensible to me.

Comment: That indeed fixed the problem. it should be noted that that part of the chip includes several analog pins as well as two or three digital pins. On the other hand, connecting aVCC to Vcc, actually reduced current by a few mA. It should also be noted that that connection requires a 100nf ceramic capacitor and a small inductor, to cut any noise form external voltage variations.

Comment: @Camilo: This is listed as an "analog noise canceling technique". If you do not use the ADC, you can connect AVCC just like VCC, with only the 100 nF cap.